# DevForce - Issue with IKnownType in case of inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, devforce

Devforce 7.4.0.0.

We have a DLL which is shared between the server and client. The goal is to make a server method which will return a list of some custom (serializable) objects.

So I declared this in the shared DLL, without creating a server method or changing anything else, and simply launched the project. It crashed. Then I slightly changed this code and it works again.

I have the same pattern with an interface with "IKnownType" and some subclasses at another place in the application and I did not have these issues. It looks like it may or may not happen, depending upon the namespaces or something which I was not able to discover.

However, this is not the first time I have issues with inheritance with DevForce. I had discovered in the other case I mentionned just before that if you made an inheritance depth higher than two levels (ie. a base type 'A' which is "IKnownType" -> B (derivates from A) -> C (derivates from B)), then I had the same kind of issues. The worst being that the message you get from DevForce does not give you a hint that the types have issues.

There's nothing in the server/client DevForce logs that mention something wrong with the types. Both of them are shown as discovered by IdeaBlade.EntityModel.KnownTypeHelper+<>c:b__5_1

I also tried an alternative based upon a IKnownTypeProvider, this times the application started but it crashed as soon as I called a server method that used the types.

Non working code, compile, launch, crash (see stack trace below):

```
    public interface IMyProjection : IKnownType {
        long Id {
            get;set;
        }
    }

    public class MyProjection : IMyProjection {
        public long Id {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Name {
            get; set;
        }

        public bool IsLocked {
            get;set;
        }
    }
```

Working code, no inheritance, compile, runs..:

```
public class MyProjection : IKnownType {
        public long Id {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Name {
            get; set;
        }

        public bool IsLocked {
            get;set;
        }
    }
```

Server stack trace:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.IEntityServerContract.Login(ILoginCredential credential)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.RemoteEntityServerProxy.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Login>b__0()
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.WCF.RetryStrategy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.RemoteEntityServerProxy.ExecuteOnServer[T](Func`1 function, IRetryPolicy policy)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem in testing.  Please send a small repro sample to IdeaBladeSupport so we can look at this further.

Comment: Can't make a repro, too much time involved in setting up the edmx as it is in our project and anonymize it. Is there a way to increase the verbosity of the logs on DevForce side to capture this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, DevForce does not have a verbosity option to control log output.   DF will look for known types when the EntityServer WCF service starts (or on the client when the proxy is created).  In the stack trace you've shown it's WCF that is complaining about the known types for some reason.  You might be able to obtain more information on the error by enabling WCF tracing - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks this might be a good starting point